# Basically Binary but Boldly Baffling

Tags: pattern, visual, sequence

Another image sequence puzzle inspired by @Conifers, enjoy ;D

> [image]

[Colorblind-friendly version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGzrl.png)

> Clarification: one or more tag(s) has been deliberately omitted to enhance the difficulty.

### **Hints**

1

> There are 3 patterns to be spotted.

2a

> [image]

2b

> In binary, which value means false, and which means true?

2c:

> $i^0=?, i^1=?...$

3:

> Hints 2a, 2b, and 2c refers to each of the 3 sequences referred to in Hint 1

4a:

> Two of the strips refer to the same number.

Comment: Thank you for the colorblind friendly version! I'll try solving once I am out of class :)

Comment: You are very welcome! It’s my responsibility as a puzzle creator to make the puzzle as accessible to all as possible, so everyone can join in the fun :) @ThatOneNerdyBoy

Comment: :D Nice inspiration~

Comment: one of these hints is CUTE!!

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis I guess it refers to the "cute sequence". But I cannot find relationships to the colors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's divide the $5$ cells like this:

> [image]

If you observe the colored cells (the non-black cells) upside-down:

> It alternates between RED-YELLOW-BLUE.

The next thing is that, the $5$ cells are actually representing the binary. With black cell denoting $0$ and colored cells denoting $1$. *(This refers to hint 2b.)* But, it's not a regular binary. It's:

> [image]
>  *(this refers to hint 2c)*

So, if we evaluate the numbers:

> [image]

Yep, you will have:

> A Fibonacci sequence!
>  *(this refers to hint 2a)*

So the final answer will be:

> [image]
>  a.k.a **BLUE-BLACK-YELLOW-BLACK-BLUE**.

Comment: The answer provided by @Namyts is pretty close (even the final answer is the same!) However, I wrote this answer without seeing it first, I missed the color part and had just found it. ><

Comment: nice work! im thinking to whom the check should go to... on one hand, you found the most important sequence (the base), but on the other hand they got the answer first...

Comment: so what is the rabbit clue??

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis See [here](https://plus.maths.org/content/fibonacci-sequence-brief-introduction) - Fibonacci's original discovery of this sequence came about as a result of a hypothesis about how many rabbit descendants a breeding pair would produce in a year... A titbit from mathematical history!

Answer (score 3):

**Partial Answer:** I'm not getting far with this. But i think it could be:

> blue black yellow black blue

This is probably nonesense but I think I can see:

> The fibonacci sequence in binary. Possibly added to another binary pattern if r=1, y=2, b=3. i.e a yellow would be a 1 in the first and second pattern. The fibonacci sequence being one of the clues matches the rabbit at least...

Below are my "workings". I fear I am also barking up the wrong tree, especially since I cant see any further patterns...

> [image: Workings]

So basically my answer was almost a complete guess :)

> The colors in my guess were just cycling red -> yellow -> blue -> red etc...

Comment: rot13(Znlor uvag 2n ersref gb gur Sv-ohaal-npv frdhrapr? Jub xabjf :b)

Comment: congrats! you have identified 2 out of 3 patterns

Comment: you got the answer, but @athin got the overall mechanism first and the most difficult part, power of -2. so im sorry but i have to award them the check, but please enjoy an pvote from me. keep your hard work up, and happy puzzling!

Comment: @Avi rot13(V yvxr gung n ybg zber guna jung v npghnyyl gubhtu, ohg V inthryl erzrzorerq svobanppv zragvbavat ohaal enoovgf va fbzr znguf dhrfgvba/rknzcyr :c)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton This was a great puzzle. Although I'm actually extremely confused why I even came close given I was rot13(va gur jebat onfr). I wonder now if the same bits would always be flipped... or was it pure coincidence and I found a pattern out of nothing.....? Lol... glad to see I wasn't impossibly far off! Didn't have too much time during my break to crack this one though; perhaps next time! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I'm thinking.

> Please note that I'm making a lot of assumption  if it's a weird an baffling binary, it must be base four (on per color) let's call them 
>
> K, R, Y, B 
> each line is a 5 digits number, in the binary system each position has a weight (2^n)
> so each position has a specific weight, let's call them, from right to left : 
> U, V, W, X, Y
>
> If we say that each of the 7 line is just counting from 1 to 7 so: 
>  r*u + k*v + h*w + k*x + k*y = 1 and so on
>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXFOO.png
>  So we've got 9 unknown variables and only 7 equations....
>  If we say, by looking at the fist line, that R = 1 and U = 1, we can solve this system.
>  I did not try to solve it right now, I'll try latter. I just want to kown what you guy think of this.

Comment: sorry but it seems like you're barking up the wrong tree. perhaps the new hints may help?